# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables while compiling python for android ON Linux Ubuntu

Tags: android, python, linux, gcc, distribute

I allready created pyton for android folder few days ago, but forgot to nclude some modules. So I just wanted to do this again...

Tis is a result of ./distribute.sh

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel   
_sqlite3           _ssl               _tkinter        
bsddb185           bz2                dbm             
gdbm               linuxaudiodev      ossaudiodev     
sunaudiodev                                           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
readline                                              

Call build_python
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux3
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... i686
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for arm-eabi-gcc... ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/pawel/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And this is the end of config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 2.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --host=arm-eabi OPT= --prefix=/home/pawel/python-for-android/build/python-install --enable-shared --disable-toolbox-glue --disable-framework

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = pawel-ThinkPad-X61-Tablet
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.13.0-24-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
PATH: /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/
PATH: /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/
PATH: /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21//tools
PATH: .
PATH: /platform-tools
PATH: /tools
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2764: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:2805: result: no
configure:2814: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:2831: result: 32-bit
configure:2988: checking MACHDEP
configure:3136: result: linux3
configure:3142: checking EXTRAPLATDIR
configure:3157: result: 
configure:3168: checking machine type as reported by uname -m
configure:3171: result: i686
configure:3184: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3228: result: no
configure:3249: checking for arm-eabi-gcc
configure:3276: result: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm
configure:3545: checking for C compiler version
configure:3554: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm --version >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (GCC) 4.8
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3565: $? = 0
configure:3554: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/configure --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-cloog=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-isl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-ppl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-isl-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.23 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.8 --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-python=/usr/local/google/home/andrewhsieh/mydroid/ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/python-config.sh --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/include/c++/4.8 --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --disable-bootstrap --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --disable-libsanitizer --enable-gold --enable-graphite=yes --with-cloog-version=0.18.0 --with-isl-version=0.11.1 --enable-eh-frame-hdr-for-static --with-arch=armv5te --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --enable-gold=default
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8 (GCC) 
configure:3565: $? = 0
configure:3554: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm -V >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3565: $? = 1
configure:3554: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm -qversion >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3565: $? = 1
configure:3585: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3607: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm  -lm conftest.c  >&5
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lm
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lc
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3611: $? = 1
configure:3649: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
| #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3654: error: in `/home/pawel/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2':
configure:3656: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-lm
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-eabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_CC='ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='arm-linux-androideabi-ar'
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS='-DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=' '\''--host=arm-eabi'\'' '\''OPT='\'' '\''--prefix=/home/pawel/python-for-android/build/python-install'\'' '\''--enable-shared'\'' '\''--disable-toolbox-glue'\'' '\''--disable-framework'\'' '\''host_alias=arm-eabi'\'' '\''CC=ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'\'' '\''CFLAGS=-DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-lm'\'''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='ccache arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm'
DEFS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXTRAMACHDEPPATH=''
EXTRAPLATDIR=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/home/pawel/python-for-android/build/python-install'
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_HG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
HGBRANCH=''
HGTAG=''
HGVERSION=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS='-lm'
LDLAST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MACHDEP='linux3'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 2.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
RANLIB='arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib'
RUNSHARED=''
SGI_ABI=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIBS=''
SIGNAL_OBJS=''
SO=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
SVNVERSION=''
THREADHEADERS=''
THREADOBJ=''
TRUE=''
UNICODE_OBJS=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
USE_SIGNAL_MODULE=''
USE_THREAD_MODULE=''
VERSION='2.7'
ac_ct_CC=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias='arm-eabi'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/pawel/python-for-android/build/python-install'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _BSD_TYPES 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

configure: exit 77
```

That is probbably the most intresting part:

```
configure:3585: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3607: ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm -DANDROID -mandroid  -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c//platforms/android-21/arch-arm  -lm conftest.c  >&5
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lm
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lc
/home/pawel/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3611: $? = 1
configure:3649: result: no
```

I've been googling for hours.. So now I've got to ask You

Envirement is set as:

```
export ANDROIDNDK="/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/" 
export ANDROIDSDK="/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/" 
export PATH=$ANDROIDNDK:$ANDROIDSDK/platform-tools:$ANDROIDSDK/tools:$PATH
```

export ANDROIDAPI=21 
export ANDROIDNDKVER=r9c