# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables in buildozer kivy

Tags: python, android, c, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to compile an apk using buildozer and kivy.

**I have `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables` error when I want to convert my kivy file to apk android file with `buildozer android debug deploy`.**

Here is the complete error:

```
  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1297, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 730, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 215, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 505, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 34, in build_arch
    '--enable-shared', _env=env)
  File "/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/elmantr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/elmantr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/elmantr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: /media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-android-strip... /home/elmantr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make -j4 supports nested variables... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc... /home/elmantr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=elmanapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'az_IR'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     LC_PAPER = 'az_IR'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'az_IR'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     MANAGERPID = '2713'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '730eb555b32c458694066550940adc12'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     USERNAME = 'elmantr'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     LC_NAME = 'az_IR'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     USER = 'elmantr'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/e5623443_face_4b77_b607_cf5202805f3b'
#     PWD = '/media/elmantr/8C7CA79C7CA77F96/programming/python/kivy'
#     HOME = '/home/elmantr'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:38945'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '2853'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/home/elmantr/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'az_IR'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=eefa6fc1f5cb65c532b63f7e634033a7'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'az_IR'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.124'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'az_IR'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'elmantr'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=eefa6fc1f5cb65c532b63f7e634033a7'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/elmantr/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/elmantr/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'az_IR'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/elmantr:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2749,unix/elmantr:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2749'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_TIME = 'az_IR'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/elmantr/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/elmantr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/elmantr/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

How can I solve the problem?

I have read these similar questions and they did not help:

[buildozer - C compiler cannot create executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468814/buildozer-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables)

[configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables while compiling python for android ON Linux Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139009/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-while-compiling-python-fo)

[buildozer android debug: c compiler error - cannot create executables - configure: exit77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979427/buildozer-android-debug-c-compiler-error-cannot-create-executables-configur)

[configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables - Buildozer kivy to android debuging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062739/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-buildozer-kivy-to-andro)

Note: My operating system is 64-bit!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue for three weeks with windows (ubuntu subsystem 20.4.1), NDK r25b, android api 31, sdk 21, p4a develop.

If I run the command that failed in the terminal everything works fine, because my system use a different compiler outside of buildozer. If I am correct, you are using Ubuntu-Gnome, so this fix may not be interesting or relevant to you:

I could solve this error by **manualy updating wsl1 to wsl2**.

Maybe you have enough knowledge in linux or someone else can explain what happend after updating wsl1 to wsl2 so you can transfer the fix for your current system.